# Un merging of Javascript array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have some collection and delivery points and there is a possibility like collecting the goods from multiple places(A, B, C) and delivering at a specific address(Z).

Similarly, There can be collect the goods from a specific address(E) and deliver at multiple places (E1, F1, G1):

For example,

```
 [
  'COLLECTION - Address A - Pepsi',
  'COLLECTION - Address B - Pizza,Olives',
  'COLLECTION - Address C - Burger',
  'DELIVERY - Address Z - Pepsi,Pizza,Olives,Burger',

  'COLLECTION - Address D - Maggi',
  'DELIVERY - Address D1 - Maggi',

  'COLLECTION - Address E - Cheese,Egg,Bread,Butter',
  'DELIVERY - Address  E1 - Cheese',
  'DELIVERY - Address F1 - Egg,Bread',
  'DELIVERY - Address G1 - Butter'
]
```

I want to unmerge this and make single entries for collection and delivery:
like as below

```
[
'COLLECTION - Address A - Pepsi',
'DELIVERY - Address Z - Pepsi',

'COLLECTION - Address B - Pizza,Olives',
'DELIVERY - Address Z - Pizza,Olives',

'COLLECTION - Address C - Burger',
'DELIVERY - Address Z - Burger',

'COLLECTION - Address D - Maggi',
'DELIVERY - Address D1 - Maggi',

'COLLECTION - Address E - Cheese',
'DELIVERY - Address  E1 - Cheese',

'COLLECTION - Address E - Egg,Bread',
'DELIVERY - Address  F1 - Egg,Bread',

'COLLECTION - Address E - Butter',
'DELIVERY - Address  G1 - Butter'
]
```

Actual array to de-merge as described above:

```
[
    {
        "type": "COLLECTION",
        "address": "Address A",
        "goods": [
            "Pepsi"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-02T12:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "COLLECTION",
        "address": "Address B",
        "goods": [
            "Pizza", "Olives"

        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-02T13:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "COLLECTION",
        "address": "Address C",
        "goods": [
            "Burger"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-02T14:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "DELIVERY",
        "address": "Address Z",
        "goods": [
            "Pepsi",
            "Pizza","Olives",
            "Burger"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-03T08:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "COLLECTION",
        "address": "Address D",
        "goods": [
            "Maggi"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-03T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "DELIVERY",
        "address": "Address D1",
        "goods": [
            "Maggi"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-03T10:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "COLLECTION",
        "address": "Address E",
        "goods": [
            "Cheese",
            "Egg",
            "Butter"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-03T08:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "DELIVERY",
        "address": "Address  E1",
        "goods": [
            "Cheese"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-03T12:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "DELIVERY",
        "address": "Address F1",
        "goods": [
            "Egg", "Bread"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-03T13:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "DELIVERY",
        "address": "Address G1",
        "goods": [
            "Butter"
        ],
        "datetime": "2022-01-03T14:00:00.000Z"
    },
]
```

I have tried to unmerge it using below function but, it is not working properly:

```
const deMergeStops = (stopList: any[]): any[] => {
    const array: any[] = [];

    stopList?.reduce((previousItem: any, currentItem: any, currentIndex) => {

        if (['COLLECTION'].includes(previousItem?.type) && currentItem?.type == 'COLLECTION') {
            array.push(previousItem);
            const nextDelivery = stopList.find((q: any, index) => index > currentIndex && q.type == 'DELIVERY');
            const deliveryStop: any = {
                ...nextDelivery,
                ...{
                    goods: previousItem.goods,
                }
            };
            array.push(deliveryStop);

        } else if (['COLLECTION'].includes(previousItem?.type) && currentItem?.type == 'DELIVERY') {
            const deliveryStop: any = {
                ...currentItem,
                ...{
                    goods: previousItem.goods,
                }
            };
            array.push(previousItem);
            array.push(deliveryStop);
        }

        previousItem = currentItem;
        return previousItem;
    }, {} as any);
    return array;
}
```

Can you help me how can I generate output as expected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You need a function?  Did you try writing one?

Comment: @mplungjan sure, I will keep this in mind. Thanks for helping!

Comment: [In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using reduce and spread. You will have to convert to typescript yourself

Note I need to deep clone the objects so I use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)

```js
const input = [ { "type": "COLLECTION", "address": "Address A", "goods": [ "Pepsi" ], "datetime": "2022-01-02T12:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "COLLECTION", "address": "Address B", "goods": [ "Pizza" ], "datetime": "2022-01-02T13:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "COLLECTION", "address": "Address C", "goods": [ "Burger" ], "datetime": "2022-01-02T14:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "DELIVERY", "address": "Address Z", "goods": [ "Pepsi", "Pizza", "Burger" ], "datetime": "2022-01-03T08:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "COLLECTION", "address": "Address D", "goods": [ "Maggi" ], "datetime": "2022-01-03T09:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "DELIVERY", "address": "Address D1", "goods": [ "Maggi" ], "datetime": "2022-01-03T10:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "COLLECTION", "address": "Address E", "goods": [ "Cheese", "Egg", "Butter" ], "datetime": "2022-01-03T08:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "DELIVERY", "address": "Address E1", "goods": [ "Cheese" ], "datetime": "2022-01-03T12:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "DELIVERY", "address": "Address F1", "goods": [ "Egg" ], "datetime": "2022-01-03T13:00:00.000Z" }, { "type": "DELIVERY", "address": "Address G1", "goods": [ "Butter" ], "datetime": "2022-01-03T14:00:00.000Z" }, ];

// create a keyed delivery table - I assume one key to one collected item
const deliveries = input.filter(({type}) => type==="DELIVERY").reduce((acc,cur) => {
  cur.goods.forEach(item => {
    acc[item] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cur))
    acc[item].goods = [item]
  })
  return acc
},{})

output = Object.entries(deliveries).reduce((acc,entry) => {
  const [key,value] = entry
  const inp = input.filter(({goods}) => goods.includes(key))[0]
  acc.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inp)))
  acc.push({...deliveries[key],goods:[key]})
  return acc
},[])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, @mplungjan, If the input has one collection with multiple goods and more delivery points then this won't manage it.

Comment: Sorry for that, but, I had edited the question and mentioned that. thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the question, please check it. thanks!

Comment: If any stops have multiple goods it is not working properly. see my input and output in question..

Comment: What is expected OUTPUT of the latest array???

Comment: It should not depend on the goods. Need to build logic to manage the scenarios. like collect the goods from different places and deliver to one place and like collect from one place and deliver to multiple different places.  so, this scenario, it should de-merge the collection/delivery places based on pattern.

Comment: It seems to me I answered the original question and you are now adding feature creep. If you cannot show me an expected output I cannot modify my answer to match your expectations